# FadeIn on scroll : lag of scroll jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

To fadeIn elements on scroll, I've took some code and use it on my site :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).scroll( function(){
    $('.fadein').each(function(i){
      var top_of_element = $(this).offset().top;
      var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
      if( bottom_of_window > top_of_element ){
        $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},1000);
      }
    });
    $('.fadeineach').each(function(i){
      var top_of_element = $('.fadeineachparent').offset().top;
      var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
      if( bottom_of_window > top_of_element ){
        $(this).delay(80 * i).animate({'opacity':'1'},1000);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

With this code, I have a good fadeIn effect on my elements :

```html
<section class="fadein">
    <p>Element of the section fadein</p>
</section>
```

And for multiple elements, on scroll on the section parent :

```html
<section class="fadeineachparent">
  <div class="card fadeineach">
    <p>Element</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card fadeineach">
    <p>Element</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card fadeineach">
    <p>Element</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Pretty sure my code isn't beautiful, but it works... :P

The problem is on Safari, and sometimes on Chrome, on scroll, the site seems to lag, it's not user friendly. I tried some things found on Internet, but nothing works... :/

Do you have an idea of what's wrong ?

Comment: have you considered simply adding a class on scroll and applying the animation to that class through css rather than attempting to have jquery animate it?

Comment: I haven't think about this possibility, do you think that can solve my lag problem ? :)

Comment: Possibly. Opacitys and transforms are great for css animations since they don't require a repaint. CSS animations that don't require repaints are up to 20x faster than jquery animations. GSAP vs css animations that require a repaint, GSAP takes the lead. 

If you don't know about the cssom, now would be the time to learn. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Performance/CSS_JavaScript_animation_performance

Comment: Okay thank you very much, I will look at this and try to make my code better :)